# WPF window slightly moves when UI thread is stuck

Tags: wpf, windows, user-interface

I noticed that when our WPF application’s GUI thread is stuck for a few seconds, the application’s main window moves a few pixels to the top and left, and then, when the GUI thread is freed, the window returns to its location.

I also noticed it happen in Visual Studio when I save a complex file and [CodeMaid](http://www.codemaid.net/) is busy cleaning it – Visual Studio window moves a few pixels to the top and left, and then, when the job is done, it returns to its previous location.

This doesn’t always happen and is not easily reproducible. It seems not to happen when the window is maximized.

Can anyone say why this happens, and, more important, how to avoid it (other than keeping the GUI thread from getting stuck…)?

Comment: If this is happening to Visual Studio in addition to your application, then it's not a bug on the part of your app. It's more than likely a bug with the Aero theming engine. Keeping your GUI thread from getting stuck sounds like a good idea, though! That's what I would focus on. Make sure that you're not running any blocking operations at all on the UI thread—spin them off onto a background thread instead.

Comment: @Cody: Working on that, but if I need to select a node in a tree that has ~10000 siblings, it must be done in GUI thread, and WPF need time for this...